# Singular perturbation - matching inner and outer solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits, asymptotics, perturbation-theory

I'm struggling with the following question.

> Construct leading-order inner and outer solutions to:
> $$ \epsilon u''(x) + u'(x) = \frac{u(x) + u(x)^3}{1 + 3u(x)^2}, $$
> $$ 0<x<1, $$
> $$ u(0)=0, $$
> $$ u(1)=1, $$
> where $ 0< \epsilon <<1 $. [You will only be able to determine the outer solution implicitly.]

Here's what I've done so far, though I'm not fully confident it's all correct.

Boundary layer is at $x=0$.

Outer expansion $u_0(x)$ satisfies:
$$ u_0'(x) = \frac{u_0(x) + u_0(x)^3}{1 + 3u_0(x)^2}. $$
This gives solution
$$ ln(u_0(x)(1+u_0(x)^2))=x+C, $$
where C is a constant of integration. Plugging in boundary condition $u_0(1)=1$ gives $C=1+\ln2$, hence our outer expansion satisfies $$ u_0(x)(1+u_0(x)^2) = 2e^{x+1} $$

Inner expansion $U_0(x)$ satisfies
$$ U_0''(x) + U_0(x) = 0. $$
This gives solution
$$ U_0(x) = A + Be^{-x}, $$
where A and B are constants of integration. Applying the other boundary condition $U_0(0)=0$ gives $A+B=0$, so $B=-A$, and hence we have inner expansion
$$ U_0(x) = A(1 - e^{-x}). $$

This is where I don't know where to continue. To find A, I need to use matching, i.e. set the inner limit of the outer solution equal to the outer limit of the inner solution. The inner limit of the outer solution is:
$$ \lim_{x \to ∞}U_0(x) = \lim_{x \to ∞}A(1-e^{-x}) = A. $$

The outer limit of the inner solution, $\lim_{x \to 0}u_0(x)$, satisfies:
$$ \lim_{x \to 0}u_0(x)(1 + u_0^2(x)) = 2e. $$

Do I then just set $A + A^3 = 2e$? I assume not, as this doesn't have a neat solution. Perhaps I went wrong further back?

Thank you so much in advance for any help!

Comment: You have a sign error in the condition at $x=1$. And yes, your last result looks like the best possible. You could apply Cardano-formulas, but I'm not sure if that will give a more explicit solution.